# How to restrict the resources within one JVM

Tags: wso2

I'm trying with WSO2 products, and I'm thinking about a scenario where bad code could take up all the CPU time (e.g. dead loop or so). I did try it with WSO2 AS with 2 tenants, A and B. And A's bad code does affect B and B's app will have a very long reponse delay or even stuck. Is there a way to restrict the CPU usage of a tenant? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you will have to setup your environment in what is known as private jet mode, where each tenant gets its own JVM, if you need total isolation.

In a shared environment, we have stuck thread detection which will ensure that critical threads will not run for more than a specified time period. We have plans for CPU usage limiting on per tenant basis. This would be available in a future release.

Comment: Thanks, Afakham! It seems private jet mode would be a better choice than in-process multi-tenancy for our use-case. You mentioned stuck thread detection, but when I experimented on my WSO2AS with a dead loop, it didn't shutdown or kill the thread. Do I need some special setup on WS2AS? I've read the documents, but I might just missed that. There're so many documents. And you also mentioned plans for CPU usage limiting, when is that going to be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to not run two tenants in one application server. Run two separate processes on the same machine. Better yet, run two separate processes in separate OS-level containers (like a [jail](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails.html) or an [lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/man/lxc.html) container). Or separate virtual machines if you can't use containers.

Operating systems give you tools for controlling CPU use - rlimit and nice for processes, and implementation-specific facilities for containers and VMs. Because they're implemented in the OS (or virtual machine manager), they are capable of doing this job correctly and reliably. There's no way an application server can do it anywhere near as well.

In any case, having separate applications share an application server and JVM is a terrible idea which should have been put to death in the '90s. There's just no need for it, and it introduces so many potential headaches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tom! But the main reason we're looking at WSO2 is its so-called mult-tenancy support, which allows us to run applications from multiple tenants. If that's no feasible, probably WSO2 is not a wise choice then.

Comment: BTW, you said the idea of having separate applications share an application server and JVM has been put to death. Will you please recommend some readings on that? Thanks!

Comment: It is not so-called multitenancy we have in the WSO2 platform. MUltitenancy has two different modes; shared resources & environment based MT & totally isolated MT. We support both. It is a deployment choice to select one of the two. We have users & customers using both. WSO2 products support in-process MT. You can run non-WSO2 products (which don't support in-process MT) within the WSO2 framework & benefit from PaaS foundation services including MT by using the new Cartridge model.

Comment: You could learn more about the supported models from http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/StratosProposal. WSO2 recently contributed Stratos PaaS foundation to Apache.

Comment: @TerryTao: +1 to your request for more evidence to back up my assertion about not sharing containers. Sadly, i don't know of anything actually written on this topic. It's just my observation that it doesn't work very well, and that nobody seems to do it these days.

Comment: In fact, i would turn it around and ask if anyone has made an argument in favour of having applications share containers. Why would you do that? If you think about non-Java applications, you'd never try to run your web server and your database in the same process. So why do the equivalent for Java?

Comment: @Afkham, thanks! it's nice to see replies from WSO2 developers, and I'm glad that Stratos becomes an Apache project. I'll take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: @Tom. Yes, I agree with your opinion that applications should not share the containers. And I've seen the trend of not using a container even for java applications. The reason I started this questions is I'm investigating the potential of in-process multi-tenancy, and its pros and cons.

Comment: Fair enough. I commend you for actually investigating it in detail!